# Node.js es6 class support

Tags: javascript, node.js

Finally es6 classes have landed in Node.js v4.0.0. But the feature needs `--use_strict` option to be passed. e.g.

```
node --use_strict sampleClass.js
```

What does this `--use_strict` option signify? Has it anything to do with "use strict"; javascript directive.

**Note:** On Linux Classes worked in v0.12 too but not in Windows

**Edit:**  If you want to omit `--use_strict` flag than use `"use strict";` in js file

Comment: I have used `class` without any flag

Comment: @intekhab Node runs something called "magic mode" where it catches syntax errors in the REPL and tries to eval them with strict mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, JS has a [strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it?rq=1) which slightly changes how scoping works as well as other small things. Generally, it should be preferred since the bodies of classes and modules are always in strict mode anyway.

Classes work both in strict and loose mode. However, the JavaScript engine Node runs only supports running classes in strict mode at the moment.

This is a limitation of V8 (the engine) and will be resolved in the future. [Here is the bug tracking it](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2198).

Comment: so you mean --use_strict flag forces "use strict"; in code even if "use strict"; has not been explicitly mentioned

Comment: @adnankamili yes, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/64beab0fc55f750bae648e9b69e027f2dbf3b18a/deps/v8/src/flag-definitions.h#L171

Answer (score 3):

[Starting from version 6](https://node.green/#ES2015-functions-class), classes in NodeJS just work, so no `--use_strict` flag is required.